# Android In-App Billing Subscription purchase gives error [DF-AA-20]

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have *in-app billing* subscriptions available to users which I would like to test and ensure the logic works as expected. However, I am unable to do so.

Note:

There are a number of SO questions relating to In-App Billing not working, specifically for this error:

> Error while retrieving information from server [DF-AA-20]

Such as can be found:
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768655/error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-aa-20), and 
 - `[here][2]`, and 
 - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777955/in-app-purchase-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-aa-20), and
 - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361216/in-app-purchase-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-aa-20-andr)

**Summarised,** all solutions relate to some missing part of the requirements.

A prominent issue is the issue of the app being tested without being published to atleas the `Alpha test track` (which I have done). *This is detailed later in the post.*

---

**Documentation:**

**Implementation**

The requirements for implementing *In-App Billing* into an Android app is as follows:

- **Add** the latest `BillingClient` in your module level gradle file:

The [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Steps) suggests:

```
`implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2.1`
```

which cannot be found by Gradle (02 Feb 2019)

Mine works with:

```
`implementation group:'com.android.billingclient', name:'billing', version:'1.2'`
```

- **Implement** the `BillingClient` providing an interface to the Android (Google) Billing Service for making purchases.

This is defined in a detailed step-wise tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview)

**Testing:**

The requirements for testing your `In-App Billing` in an Android app is as follows:

**For Solo tests**

- For `In-App purchases` *solo tests*, one can test these using the static test responses defined [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#billing-testing-static)
- Subscriptions cannot be *solo tested*, they need have other conditions

> Note: Static responses cannot be used to test subscriptions.

**For Testing with Testers** ([see here for more](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-purchases))

- Create a Open/Closed track for testing and add the testers you wish to allow for testing. Upload the app to the relevant test track and you MUST publish. Uploading the app as a draft does not work anymore

> Note: Previously you could test an app by uploading an unpublished
>   "draft" version. This functionality is no longer supported. However,
>   you can test your app with static responses even before you upload it
>   to the Google Play Store. For more information, see Test with static
>   responses.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#billing-testing-static) for more details,

- One-Time subscriptions are explained in further detail [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-onetime)
- Subscription purchases work as expected, but the subscription times are heavily shortened to emulate the subscription times. Read in further detail [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-subscriptions).

**Note:**
To allow for testing, the app must be published, in atleast the test track. This makes the subscriptions available to that version of the app.

*Note 2:
It appears that various users have had issues testing on the same Google account as their developer account. Make sure to use a different tester account which is not the same as your developer account. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41378963/4628115) for details*

**Note 3**
*I saw the documentation made mention of a public key use for licensing, but the in-app purchase tutorial did not require it during implementation. I am not sure if this is causing my issue*

**Problem:**

Having followed all of these steps above, I am unable to successfully purchase a subscription.

- I download the test app to an emulator (with Google Play services active).

*The test account also has a card payment method setup prior to downloading.*

- I proceed to purchase the subscription, then the following is shown:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have not familiar with issue, but we always use public license key with implementation.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya could you provide me an example of where and how the public license key would be implemented into the `BillingClient` or otherwise.

Comment: Did you add testers before publishing the app? If not, then it might be an issue as well.

Comment: @SnehaSarkar testers were added on initial release. To confirm they could access the test app, they could see the updated description I added when publishing the test app.

Comment: Does it work if you download the app to a real phone rather than an emulator? And how are you installing the app - via sideload or from the play store? If it is via sideload, what happens if you install it from the Play store?

Comment: Hi, @KGCybeX did you manage to resolve the issue? I have tried everything and can't get to know what the problem is!

Comment: @KGCybeX Hi, do your emulator has multiple google account? If yes, then remove others and make sure the tester account is added as the primary account in your device before proceeding. I had the same issue and this solved my problem.

Comment: @SnehaSarkar thanks for the advice, but I had only 1 account on my emulator. This was tested on my physical device too, which had multiple accounts

Answer (score 0):

For testing, use SKU_ID or Product_ID as "**android.test.purchased**",

there is also library that's easy to use, have a look

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned in my post under the `solo-tests`, the `android.test.purchased` is used only for in-app purchases (one time purchases). The bullet point following the brief solo-test one time purchase explanation shows that `Static responses cannot be used to test subscriptions.`. My app uses subscriptions as already stated, not one time purchases.

Comment: I understand sir, Have a look at library link, they provide subscription support too also they store history too. Hope it helps

Comment: I have implemented my own wrapper for the BillingClient. The code is not the problem. The problem lies with the response on Google's side, where the subsciptions are not available or some other code-UNrelated issue. So, no matter the code/library I use, it will not be solved.